# How to disable swiping with 3 fingers from popping up a Virtual Desktop configuration window?

Tags: touchpad, themes, xfce, workspaces, multi-touch

On a fresh Xubuntu 20.04 LTS installation with Chicago95, I've created 4 virtual desktops. **When I swipe across my laptop trackpad with 3 fingers, a window for configuring my Workspaces shows up**, showing my running apps and asks if I want to add or remove a workspace:

[image]

How can I disable this from happening? I've checked the Window Manager Tweaks page, the keyboard shortcuts page, and the workspace settings page itself, but found nothing (including what this window is called).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I get this window when I middle-click the desktop. I think you can disable it in "desktop settings"->"menus"

Answer (score 0):

Per @HolyBlackCat's comment, you can disable this in Desktop > Menus, untoggle "Show window list menu on middle click"